# Fastest way to search a keyword in 500 articles in real time

Tags: javascript, html, performance, search

I have a modal that contains **500** plus articles but only **3** lines of them and their title are visible.

When you search a keyword, say **`lorem ipsem`**, I want to show all articles that contains it and hide the rest of them. It happens on **`input.onkeyup`**.  I have tested two different methods to do so:

## #1

This code to search for the keyword in all of the articles' `innerText`. If a column contains the keyword, show it and hide otherwise.

```js
const keyword = event.target.value.trim().toLowerCase();
const columns = document.querySelectorAll('.articles');
if (keyword.length > 0) {
  for (let column of columns) {
    if (column.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) === -1) {
      column.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      column.style.display = "flex";
    }
  }
} else {
  for (let column of columns) {
    column.style.display = "flex";
  }
}
```

## #2

Used the js built-in `filter` method to filter the articles, regenerate the `template` of the articles, remove the existent articles from the `DOM`, and then append the new one.

```js
const keyword = event.target.value.trim().toLowerCase();
const regex = new RegExp(`${keyword}`, 'gi');
const helpArticles = Utils.getItem("helpArticles")
  .filter(article => article['title'].toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) !== -1 || article['desc_un_html'].toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) !== -1)
```

*I have not included the code I use to generate the template. In case if you wonder, comment and I will do so*

---

The first approach is faster than the second one. There is only like a second delay until the result is visible. But the project manager thinks it is slow. Are there better/faster ways to search a keyword in 500 articles?

Comment: Have you tried `debounce` on your input.keyup?  A second delay on each keypress is very frustrating - especially as starting with a short text (eg "e") will give a lot of results.  So you debounce the input so that it waits until the user has finished typing before starting the search (doesn't help if user types really slowly ofc...)

Comment: Also, if you want to increase performance keep DOM access to a minimum. It looks like you're making multiple per iteration of the loop.

Comment: Couple of other speed improvements: don't change `.style.display` 1 at a time, instead find the ones you want and change all of them at the same time (edit: as Rory put it more eloquently: keep DOM access to a minimum).   `.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword)` might be quicker with a case-insensitive regex if there's quite a bit of text in each article.

Comment: Get your server to return a JSON array keyed by article ID and which contains the keywords. Then on the frontend you would run your search against the JSON, collate the matching ID's, then you only have a minor DOM interaction to show/hide. This should visually appear to be almost instant.

Comment: @freedomn-m Would not use a regex but a suffix tree - see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pattern-searching-using-suffix-tree/

Comment: @mahan Do you always search through the same articles? This means, is the list of articles rarely changing? If yes, apart from suffix trees, lookup tables where commonly used search terrms are getting stored may greatly improve search speed.

Comment: @freedomn-m I use debounce now, and it is a little better.Thanks. What you mean by `toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword)` ? Could you let me know how can i change the style of all articles that contains the keyword or don't?

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa   I do not know the search terms beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

this is perfect for prefix-tree,  i build an example how to use it using this lib that implement the tree

[prefix-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prefix-tree)

in the example i use around 300 divs with random text

notice the the upper code is the lib its self and the bottom code is the search

```js
function Tree(items) {
  this._root = { children: {}, value: null };
  (items || []).forEach(function(item) {
    this.set(item[0], item[1])
  }, this);
}
Tree.prototype._find = function(key) {
  var length = key.length;
  if (!length) {
    return undefined;
  }

  var node = this._root;
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (node.children[key[i]]) {
      node = node.children[key[i]];
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  }

  return node;
};

Tree.prototype.get = function(prefix) {
  var match = this._find(prefix || '');
  if (!match) { return []; }

  var nodes = [match];
  var res = [];
  var n = 0;
  var node, i, keys;

  while(n < nodes.length) {
    node = nodes[n];
    node.value && res.push(node.value);
    keys = Object.keys(node.children);
    for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      nodes.push(node.children[keys[i]]);
    }
    n++;
  }

  return res;
};

Tree.prototype.set = function(key, value) {
  var node = this._root;
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
    if (node.children[key[i]]) {
      node = node.children[key[i]];
    } else {
      node = node.children[key[i]] = { children: {} };
    }
  }

  node.value = value;
  return this;
};

var _treeToString =function() { return '[object Tree]'; };
Tree.prototype.toString = function() {
  return _treeToString(this._root);
};



///////////////// end of lib/////////////////////////////////






const t = new Tree();
const columns = document.querySelectorAll('.articles');
for (let column of columns) {
  t.set(column.innerText.toLowerCase(),column) 
}

window.search = function(event){

  console.time('search took ');


  columns.forEach(column =>{

     if(column.style.display !== "none"){
      column.style.display = " none";
    } 
  })

   t.get(event.target.value.toLowerCase()).forEach(column =>{
      column.style.display = "block";
  }) 

console.timeEnd('search took ');

}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder='search' onkeyup="search(event)">


<div class="articles">Cras felis ut.</div><div class="articles">Nulla lacus non imperdiet dapibus venenatis pulvinar fringilla nullam, tellus sit mattis metus.</div><div class="articles">Nulla vestibulum porta primis velit at sem, consequat augue.</div><div class="articles">Velit posuere vitae euismod platea, sagittis iaculis feugiat nibh quisque, duis scelerisque hac!</div><div class="articles">Fames hac fringilla.</div><div class="articles">Tincidunt neque ut non nisl lobortis per pharetra suspendisse.</div><div class="articles">Commodo donec platea, a porta vel ante laoreet nullam in curae justo, aliquet imperdiet sapien tortor.</div><div class="articles">Cras vulputate sollicitudin curabitur feugiat potenti.</div><div class="articles">Accumsan maecenas integer tristique tempor ante?</div><div class="articles">Vehicula placerat duis?</div><div class="articles">Curabitur est auctor vel scelerisque turpis, aenean class potenti cras per, mollis blandit euismod!</div><div class="articles">Amet nisi morbi sed est?</div><div class="articles">Suspendisse tortor conubia class id quisque cras per, orci aliquam, non himenaeos venenatis nullam, bibendum consectetur risus libero, nunc nullam primis curabitur porttitor?</div><div class="articles">Conubia malesuada purus!</div><div class="articles">Sollicitudin velit.</div><div class="articles">Praesent dui augue semper iaculis.</div><div class="articles">Faucibus erat orci luctus tempor nibh dolor metus convallis?</div><div class="articles">Per proin at etiam maecenas quisque aliquet dapibus scelerisque, nam litora lobortis auctor integer risus nostra!</div><div class="articles">Varius dapibus vel luctus imperdiet!</div><div class="articles">Donec condimentum felis erat orci fermentum.</div><div class="articles">Dolor egestas ultricies tellus at non, class est aenean ut taciti curabitur ut, erat suspendisse.</div><div class="articles">Hendrerit proin fusce nostra blandit ac class, elementum sapien facilisis nibh donec sed, torquent pellentesque?</div><div class="articles">Rutrum felis volutpat consequat nulla, dictum posuere sagittis ultrices sem gravida laoreet, fusce risus pulvinar tellus.</div><div class="articles">Nunc elit ut amet aliquet litora, quis sapien pretium sociosqu purus laoreet, urna vivamus.</div><div class="articles">Vehicula netus per et ligula neque laoreet eleifend nec.</div><div class="articles">Nisl pharetra justo quisque nullam nostra torquent accumsan molestie potenti vitae!</div><div class="articles">Euismod nostra tempus mollis fringilla, viverra fusce morbi porta!</div><div class="articles">Nulla nec class rhoncus.</div><div class="articles">Enim volutpat mauris purus quisque scelerisque blandit senectus, per molestie!</div><div class="articles">Imperdiet ultrices etiam ultrices nibh eget auctor vivamus pulvinar, accumsan interdum nisl etiam.</div><div class="articles">A rhoncus facilisis tellus aenean consequat?</div><div class="articles">Nec cursus dictum donec, fermentum sed non eget feugiat donec!</div><div class="articles">Ut semper purus placerat torquent, sem morbi praesent?</div><div class="articles">Enim dolor class.</div><div class="articles">Ut viverra praesent himenaeos vehicula tortor!</div><div class="articles">Nec at etiam magna metus inceptos interdum ut.</div><div class="articles">Egestas quisque.</div><div class="articles">Bibendum leo auctor per eros scelerisque, ante dictumst cursus elementum.</div><div class="articles">Primis eleifend semper pretium euismod cubilia eget aliquet mattis est.</div><div class="articles">In bibendum ac phasellus donec fringilla ac ultricies pharetra.</div><div class="articles">Proin consectetur aliquet sem curabitur aliquam, dictumst eros nullam ullamcorper!</div><div class="articles">Eu interdum lacus nunc placerat rhoncus conubia.</div><div class="articles">Leo neque nibh, praesent aliquam ad metus fermentum odio risus arcu.</div><div class="articles">Velit vivamus taciti aliquet suspendisse, consequat congue dui curabitur fringilla egestas eleifend sagittis.</div><div class="articles">Venenatis augue lectus congue lectus!</div><div class="articles">Massa donec porttitor arcu dictum convallis.</div><div class="articles">Lobortis cubilia interdum quis nisi lacinia?</div><div class="articles">Ullamcorper lorem litora placerat pellentesque?</div><div class="articles">Duis at tincidunt blandit venenatis posuere nunc ligula aptent euismod?</div><div class="articles">Aliquam varius per eleifend varius!</div><div class="articles">Nisl consequat rhoncus egestas nec dui, enim molestie elit.</div><div class="articles">Eleifend erat a dictum, facilisis tellus tincidunt risus duis dolor vivamus.</div><div class="articles">Neque sapien praesent et habitasse sapien tincidunt arcu dui at!</div><div class="articles">Cubilia sociosqu at libero a suscipit.</div><div class="articles">Rutrum lectus morbi aenean rhoncus integer quam mattis.</div><div class="articles">Donec dictumst dictum sagittis dictumst molestie non, egestas ipsum.</div><div class="articles">Nullam aptent sit senectus, aliquam aenean ad hac morbi, auctor congue enim suspendisse.</div><div class="articles">Erat mollis et rutrum ultrices varius.</div><div class="articles">Porttitor nisl justo lectus, in feugiat dictumst aenean viverra porta ipsum etiam porttitor nisl ante donec, venenatis etiam?</div><div class="articles">Sociosqu ad lobortis cursus odio, non quisque consequat posuere litora, quam iaculis dapibus mollis?</div><div class="articles">Accumsan fusce venenatis sed luctus eros nam dolor aenean.</div><div class="articles">Et justo aliquam diam vulputate, proin ante consequat hendrerit tortor.</div><div class="articles">Purus vel volutpat.</div><div class="articles">Donec porta ultricies quam himenaeos gravida morbi nisl.</div><div class="articles">Nisi urna aenean ullamcorper litora nostra nunc hendrerit nulla, faucibus porttitor duis enim accumsan nam feugiat dictum.</div><div class="articles">Phasellus tortor tellus nisi, integer platea vehicula etiam.</div><div class="articles">Eleifend consectetur rutrum, sem nisi tellus, purus nostra sollicitudin commodo.</div><div class="articles">Dolor aliquam luctus, quisque accumsan auctor hendrerit pharetra, suspendisse enim, laoreet suscipit curae quis, blandit vivamus proin.</div><div class="articles">Pellentesque varius dui potenti?</div><div class="articles">Scelerisque in varius etiam nec tristique neque ornare magna non diam eget litora.</div><div class="articles">Feugiat aenean sit tortor adipiscing varius rutrum vulputate, senectus sodales elementum!</div><div class="articles">Tempor condimentum potenti hac laoreet tristique, imperdiet sem euismod tellus?</div><div class="articles">Augue facilisis sed nam placerat euismod vestibulum pharetra luctus, sodales vitae?</div><div class="articles">Urna sit curabitur taciti potenti nisl, aliquam elementum iaculis.</div><div class="articles">Orci commodo nibh fames ante luctus sit ut interdum mi nec fames convallis?</div><div class="articles">Enim orci quisque egestas quam enim massa?</div><div class="articles">Aliquam netus curabitur et quis!</div><div class="articles">Venenatis sit rhoncus tempor erat diam, platea consectetur senectus.</div><div class="articles">Convallis est ligula augue curabitur est pretium.</div><div class="articles">Consectetur posuere ullamcorper aenean.</div><div class="articles">Justo posuere auctor accumsan nisi duis erat diam, nisl consectetur quis congue, dapibus lobortis ornare?</div><div class="articles">Lacus malesuada imperdiet suscipit tincidunt.</div><div class="articles">Nisl tellus in cras purus convallis nullam ipsum varius!</div><div class="articles">Nisl sodales pulvinar inceptos ipsum lorem senectus congue diam quisque, metus neque curabitur enim, aliquet et nisi sociosqu nibh conubia litora.</div><div class="articles">Enim consequat habitant iaculis felis metus erat volutpat fames scelerisque!</div><div class="articles">Nibh morbi quisque blandit interdum?</div><div class="articles">Dolor felis eleifend ultrices maecenas, tristique dictum erat litora.</div><div class="articles">Odio torquent ornare pharetra!</div><div class="articles">Ad aliquam lorem est.</div><div class="articles">Nisl gravida eleifend neque morbi class nullam.</div><div class="articles">In torquent fusce felis?</div><div class="articles">Erat auctor gravida aliquet nostra fringilla, interdum netus leo vel faucibus.</div><div class="articles">Tristique sed class scelerisque aenean, integer fusce?</div><div class="articles">Habitant dui etiam netus aliquam augue lobortis pulvinar ligula, ad varius.</div><div class="articles">Tempor praesent sodales convallis torquent, purus vitae nisi sollicitudin taciti laoreet, tristique ornare primis aenean interdum.</div><div class="articles">Suscipit magna nunc potenti, auctor mollis.</div><div class="articles">Fames malesuada orci!</div><div class="articles">Mattis duis facilisis, nunc elementum sagittis aliquam proin ultrices, erat neque odio enim, viverra libero eleifend!</div><div class="articles">Vel vulputate sem ut duis, lorem quisque mauris bibendum.</div><div class="articles">Quisque tristique morbi, class nibh egestas.</div><div class="articles">Tortor sollicitudin donec semper elit.</div><div class="articles">Dui justo iaculis odio etiam cras!</div><div class="articles">Molestie duis ornare.</div><div class="articles">Varius hendrerit!</div><div class="articles">Ut felis urna risus bibendum et eu, ultricies taciti?</div><div class="articles">Nunc commodo volutpat praesent varius!</div><div class="articles">Interdum eget lacus donec!</div><div class="articles">Dui consectetur pharetra nisl nec orci, massa nulla dictumst nostra ornare ut vestibulum scelerisque blandit.</div><div class="articles">Fermentum faucibus vulputate eleifend quisque leo auctor ut non, eleifend sociosqu donec dui imperdiet, habitant aliquam integer, sodales ut varius lobortis sollicitudin himenaeos.</div><div class="articles">Eget duis aliquet massa volutpat vestibulum aptent dapibus tempus laoreet facilisis mi aenean nibh.</div><div class="articles">Lacus fusce donec rhoncus suspendisse habitant felis sapien, rhoncus quis conubia?</div><div class="articles">Sociosqu ultricies aliquam suscipit, proin molestie eleifend ut netus, fringilla quisque?</div><div class="articles">Sapien urna scelerisque libero curae.</div><div class="articles">Erat integer condimentum ultricies, mauris tristique taciti urna aliquet rutrum, ac mi erat morbi erat tincidunt.</div><div class="articles">Accumsan dapibus pulvinar, donec lorem torquent mattis id nostra sed?</div><div class="articles">Lacus pulvinar donec dui.</div><div class="articles">Pellentesque torquent sem, nisi duis, hendrerit scelerisque adipiscing consectetur, risus ac metus donec interdum turpis.</div><div class="articles">Ultricies in sociosqu phasellus nulla quisque aliquam fermentum condimentum etiam sed porta.</div><div class="articles">Vulputate aenean laoreet per ut lectus tortor donec platea turpis!</div><div class="articles">Massa neque massa.</div><div class="articles">Mi interdum habitasse nulla habitant.</div><div class="articles">Venenatis nec?</div><div class="articles">Fermentum duis!</div><div class="articles">Blandit laoreet fermentum eget at donec placerat, primis dolor quisque risus, habitant class justo.</div><div class="articles">Proin commodo nunc ac ut.</div><div class="articles">Mollis vulputate vitae velit primis cras.</div><div class="articles">Hendrerit erat faucibus nostra nec?</div><div class="articles">Dictumst laoreet accumsan.</div><div class="articles">Vestibulum aenean egestas auctor tempus torquent.</div><div class="articles">Habitasse amet conubia dui fusce ultrices, magna dolor?</div><div class="articles">Dolor class nam commodo tincidunt aliquam elit.</div><div class="articles">Etiam quis pulvinar eget augue nisl gravida pellentesque tortor tempor vivamus platea pellentesque nisl hac!</div><div class="articles">Interdum donec odio eros?</div><div class="articles">Cursus leo quam, luctus semper vitae curabitur a, euismod elementum eros conubia?</div><div class="articles">Curabitur congue commodo!</div><div class="articles">Ligula ultricies convallis eros!</div><div class="articles">Dolor elit conubia tincidunt?</div><div class="articles">Quam placerat fermentum interdum dui netus risus malesuada!</div><div class="articles">Tellus pretium habitasse ad, nostra fames nullam, sed blandit.</div><div class="articles">Varius et suscipit quam, id semper phasellus neque hendrerit cubilia accumsan facilisis potenti.</div><div class="articles">Vitae ornare egestas nec eget platea id neque!</div><div class="articles">Vel habitasse proin primis inceptos diam, curabitur massa rutrum.</div><div class="articles">At non.</div><div class="articles">Nec litora odio ut donec condimentum himenaeos in varius torquent quisque, euismod morbi.</div><div class="articles">Condimentum eleifend.</div><div class="articles">Quis platea pulvinar condimentum habitasse ultrices.</div><div class="articles">Congue interdum tristique aptent suscipit justo, interdum gravida elementum donec habitasse?</div><div class="articles">Tellus ad varius venenatis erat tristique.</div><div class="articles">Arcu pulvinar commodo habitant risus venenatis turpis commodo senectus sollicitudin!</div><div class="articles">Curae hac odio.</div><div class="articles">Luctus ligula.</div><div class="articles">Congue mauris mattis ac erat vulputate adipiscing etiam nullam.</div><div class="articles">Cubilia curabitur suscipit in tempor suspendisse.</div><div class="articles">Augue quisque tellus quisque sed!</div><div class="articles">Enim vehicula sociosqu purus donec, vestibulum ullamcorper.</div><div class="articles">Venenatis lacus!</div><div class="articles">Ante imperdiet quisque lacinia.</div><div class="articles">Litora cras.</div><div class="articles">Augue suscipit nostra hac.</div><div class="articles">Phasellus commodo rhoncus vehicula erat cras.</div><div class="articles">Class sit?</div><div class="articles">Dui fames felis libero purus enim maecenas mauris volutpat, nisl habitasse mauris viverra eget ut ad feugiat lobortis suspendisse sem!</div><div class="articles">Duis nec eros, in dolor faucibus lorem nostra.</div><div class="articles">Lacinia dictumst egestas torquent himenaeos purus nisl per platea elit id placerat etiam, non aenean.</div><div class="articles">Rhoncus consectetur libero mollis eros volutpat dui risus, id aenean enim.</div><div class="articles">Tincidunt euismod lacus nullam taciti etiam a venenatis aliquam laoreet magna mollis condimentum, phasellus sagittis!</div><div class="articles">Per augue arcu senectus nulla purus felis!</div><div class="articles">Sapien curabitur accumsan?</div><div class="articles">Pharetra tincidunt taciti hendrerit cursus aliquam?</div><div class="articles">Nullam faucibus congue eros vivamus.</div><div class="articles">Vitae accumsan quam imperdiet vehicula, venenatis augue fames tincidunt faucibus ultricies.</div><div class="articles">Ut morbi inceptos interdum nam.</div><div class="articles">Velit et ultrices cursus bibendum?</div><div class="articles">Habitasse faucibus dui quisque tincidunt.</div><div class="articles">Nulla aenean vehicula rhoncus non, nisi magna quisque.</div><div class="articles">Tempus condimentum enim porta dapibus velit facilisis?</div><div class="articles">Vel tempor torquent!</div><div class="articles">Venenatis luctus quisque dapibus morbi, etiam malesuada donec risus etiam.</div><div class="articles">Sollicitudin sem odio, suspendisse sit consequat ipsum, eleifend conubia enim mollis litora, eu nisi.</div><div class="articles">Ornare sapien fames eros.</div><div class="articles">Posuere feugiat metus tincidunt nibh!</div><div class="articles">Eu fringilla enim pellentesque hendrerit vestibulum, ante vitae, ultrices mattis turpis aliquet blandit malesuada.</div><div class="articles">Ut per orci euismod donec.</div><div class="articles">Himenaeos in erat litora ullamcorper?</div><div class="articles">Tristique vehicula mauris est pharetra per convallis.</div><div class="articles">Maecenas vehicula torquent lectus imperdiet.</div><div class="articles">Porta lectus nostra inceptos aenean.</div><div class="articles">Potenti ad netus aliquam et litora maecenas, cras hac semper?</div><div class="articles">Consequat aliquet faucibus tempus, non ac!</div><div class="articles">Fermentum sit lacus justo fames sociosqu cubilia bibendum pulvinar, tellus porttitor justo sociosqu?</div><div class="articles">Posuere nunc magna aliquam odio curae tristique viverra aliquam?</div><div class="articles">A dolor fames scelerisque phasellus mi urna, mattis sollicitudin gravida tempus dictumst.</div><div class="articles">Habitant nibh rhoncus sem diam vulputate?</div><div class="articles">Faucibus malesuada fusce quisque rhoncus fusce tempus mauris dictum?</div><div class="articles">Fusce orci aenean nibh nulla convallis dictum orci cursus, aenean habitasse.</div><div class="articles">Lacinia fames donec habitant luctus fermentum sociosqu mollis maecenas!</div><div class="articles">Facilisis faucibus curabitur magna ad morbi magna!</div><div class="articles">Est quis porta aliquam.</div><div class="articles">Taciti velit dui mollis consectetur congue curabitur tincidunt consectetur sapien.</div><div class="articles">Ac sapien rutrum.</div><div class="articles">Justo cursus lobortis.</div><div class="articles">Netus velit vestibulum bibendum fames habitant libero.</div><div class="articles">Curae laoreet commodo.</div><div class="articles">Placerat maecenas malesuada pretium ut lacus, semper praesent vehicula massa et dapibus pretium nullam, massa arcu!</div><div class="articles">Ornare senectus cras vel netus libero vivamus faucibus?</div><div class="articles">Tristique ad id per sollicitudin fermentum.</div><div class="articles">Fusce sollicitudin fermentum.</div><div class="articles">Non ante sit libero diam lorem!</div><div class="articles">Suspendisse etiam eleifend laoreet dapibus, suspendisse et viverra quisque class nisl pellentesque!</div><div class="articles">Odio inceptos!</div><div class="articles">Urna orci donec dapibus nisi?</div><div class="articles">Neque quisque consequat.</div><div class="articles">Etiam molestie consectetur, turpis vitae taciti duis vitae morbi metus euismod.</div><div class="articles">Nunc rhoncus est aenean, ac commodo placerat vehicula.</div><div class="articles">Dapibus ut libero, sagittis bibendum laoreet luctus, eleifend viverra tortor.</div><div class="articles">Feugiat libero est dictumst fringilla!</div><div class="articles">Lacinia consequat est tincidunt vehicula.</div><div class="articles">Luctus fusce dui, sociosqu potenti rhoncus?</div><div class="articles">Porta nam pulvinar per ullamcorper ante.</div><div class="articles">Facilisis phasellus varius ut.</div><div class="articles">Phasellus etiam mollis.</div><div class="articles">Amet vulputate enim erat in, litora nibh?</div><div class="articles">Mi fames tristique phasellus, vestibulum morbi mi imperdiet.</div><div class="articles">Potenti etiam congue vel.</div><div class="articles">Cubilia sed fames arcu massa, primis consectetur nec pretium vivamus iaculis nullam donec, sit mauris eleifend quisque?</div><div class="articles">Conubia lacinia diam hac, pellentesque mi class euismod, volutpat integer est dictumst pellentesque cursus erat ipsum.</div><div class="articles">Et auctor semper consectetur litora.</div><div class="articles">Commodo at malesuada vel, morbi dictumst sit conubia taciti, venenatis justo diam venenatis viverra rhoncus cubilia lectus.</div><div class="articles">Massa aliquet congue metus aliquet nostra habitant tempus varius?</div><div class="articles">Tincidunt sollicitudin non quisque nisi a, litora class eros ut?</div><div class="articles">Mauris viverra rutrum in dolor euismod dui?</div><div class="articles">Vestibulum gravida consequat sapien aliquet himenaeos blandit viverra praesent, elementum dapibus vestibulum.</div><div class="articles">Ut tempus etiam ornare, nisi molestie dolor, sociosqu libero velit blandit.</div><div class="articles">Tellus porttitor lobortis fusce ante class malesuada curabitur nec tincidunt etiam ad aptent!</div><div class="articles">Semper pellentesque et?</div><div class="articles">Ultricies eget fusce neque senectus velit vitae, cursus aliquam habitant aenean sed.</div><div class="articles">Habitant nec fringilla, urna integer senectus mauris.</div><div class="articles">Fringilla sociosqu magna tellus id vulputate nostra, semper congue in sem faucibus?</div><div class="articles">Fames dictum consequat risus, ipsum at accumsan?</div><div class="articles">Ut metus dolor venenatis egestas curabitur rhoncus.</div><div class="articles">Blandit id pulvinar quisque a id dictumst!</div><div class="articles">Viverra nullam etiam posuere velit ipsum, mauris cras duis venenatis!</div><div class="articles">Vitae ligula donec euismod cursus suscipit molestie rutrum lectus sem curabitur sem!</div><div class="articles">Sem curabitur cursus donec.</div><div class="articles">Sit aenean purus, non in iaculis ac fusce, interdum blandit dolor.</div><div class="articles">Rhoncus id suspendisse sodales velit diam aliquam volutpat consequat curabitur!</div><div class="articles">Ante cubilia magna aliquam dolor, vitae ultrices praesent ornare est suspendisse?</div><div class="articles">Fusce vivamus sollicitudin himenaeos, porttitor torquent augue senectus.</div><div class="articles">Sem aliquam fusce bibendum aliquam quis?</div><div class="articles">Porta adipiscing quisque euismod elementum fusce, euismod convallis sociosqu?</div><div class="articles">Volutpat lacinia platea amet ipsum magna taciti porttitor conubia ultrices ligula lacus, pharetra netus tellus.</div><div class="articles">Lobortis ac convallis scelerisque ad mollis!</div><div class="articles">Class molestie a hac lobortis per tortor, aptent sem netus torquent accumsan erat ipsum euismod, quisque nostra pellentesque?</div><div class="articles">Ante aliquam augue diam mauris dictum torquent?</div><div class="articles">Diam senectus vel porttitor libero tortor!</div><div class="articles">Dictumst aliquam mollis, nulla amet semper sagittis donec laoreet aliquet, pellentesque massa malesuada, integer elementum cras, faucibus volutpat.</div><div class="articles">Orci id feugiat!</div><div class="articles">Scelerisque sapien duis ultricies porta justo placerat aptent fringilla sem torquent, quis ac imperdiet!</div><div class="articles">Vulputate vestibulum tempor.</div><div class="articles">Sagittis tristique imperdiet platea scelerisque volutpat elementum.</div><div class="articles">Tincidunt habitant sem curae sem, lobortis nibh auctor neque!</div><div class="articles">Taciti quisque ad scelerisque, eget nibh bibendum vitae non vehicula diam rhoncus, elementum et conubia magna diam, vel tellus.</div><div class="articles">Aptent nostra augue commodo aliquam lacinia, taciti nec nisi!</div><div class="articles">Semper nisi aliquet, auctor volutpat tellus, etiam scelerisque sem accumsan!</div><div class="articles">Gravida velit risus tortor et faucibus hac vivamus posuere.</div><div class="articles">Tempor tortor fames, consequat augue, urna consequat consectetur, ante congue consectetur conubia dapibus.</div><div class="articles">Risus viverra accumsan nullam nunc ullamcorper dui platea felis id augue!</div><div class="articles">Ante mi vitae!</div><div class="articles">Facilisis malesuada tincidunt aptent phasellus dictumst nostra, class taciti sed fringilla curabitur, feugiat libero fermentum quis condimentum curae, a urna eleifend vulputate.</div><div class="articles">Rutrum dolor vivamus viverra, facilisis donec curabitur mauris litora mauris vehicula turpis!</div><div class="articles">Vivamus condimentum torquent aenean vestibulum interdum auctor.</div><div class="articles">Morbi aliquet gravida consectetur, molestie ut augue malesuada adipiscing vulputate leo nam ligula himenaeos sollicitudin?</div><div class="articles">Dolor tellus integer, cubilia viverra!</div><div class="articles">Aenean pretium quis luctus dapibus proin iaculis.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am working on it and will let you know. If it solve my problem, I will for sure accept the answer.

Comment: It does not find all of the articles that I am searching for. For example, there are at least `80` articles that contains **articles**, but it finds only 8-9 of them.

Comment: @mahan this is an example of a prefix tree. its always search from the start of the word. if the word is in the word is in the middle it wont find it. if you need a full text search you need a suffix tree